# Is there a way to use a named slot more than once in a Vue 3 component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Assuming I have a component `Section`, which can have 1-N subsections and a styled footer, is there a way to do something like this?

```js
<Section>
  // main content
  <template #subsection>
    // subsection 1
  </template>
  <template #subsection>
    // subsection 2
  </template>
  <template #footer>
    // footer
  </template>
</Section>
```

Typically I would model this as repeated child components inside of the parent but in this case the styling is easier to do in the parent on slots.

Is there a way to allow repeated use of a named slot?

Comment: Why not name your slot subsection1 and subsection2 ?

Comment: names for slots are meant to be _unique_ identifiers for inserting specific content.  they're not meant for your use case unfortunately.

Comment: @Duannx - good idea, I was just hoping to have a solution where I didn't have to add additional code complexity for each one